# LIKE в SQL запросе игнорируется

Tags: mysql

Тело запроса:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.url, p.brand_id, p.name, p.annotation, p.body, p.position, p.created as created, 
 p.visible, p.featured, p.meta_title, p.meta_keywords, p.meta_description, b.name as brand, b.url 
 as brand_url
 FROM s_products p INNER JOIN s_products_categories pc 
 ON 
 pc.product_id = p.id AND pc.category_id in('10','11','6')
 LEFT JOIN s_brands b ON p.brand_id = b.id WHERE 1 AND p.visible=1  
 GROUP BY p.id 
 ORDER BY (SELECT pv.price FROM s_variants pv
 WHERE (pv.stock IS NULL OR pv.stock>0) AND p.id = pv.product_id 
 AND pv.position=(SELECT MIN(position)  and pv.name like'S' 
 FROM s_variants
 WHERE (stock>0 OR stock IS NULL) AND product_id=p.id LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1) LIMIT 0, 4
```

Пытаюсь получить все товары, входящие в определенную категорию и которые имеют определенную метку в названии варианта, но вот эта конкретная строка  `and pv.name like'S'`  похоже вообще игнорируется. По ссылке дамп базы.

http://dropmefiles.com/VKUBf

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на [синтаксис оператора `LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) и на то, как вы его используете.

Comment: чем может помочь ваш `like` в `order by` не совсем понятно. `order by` - это сортировка, каждой отобранной записи. по-моему, вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: Вы правы.
Мне необходимо использовать еще 1 джоин?

Comment: да еще один join просто, надо связать варианты с товарами по этому like'у, и шаблон для like как в ответе вам написали.

Answer (score 3):

так делаейте like [правильно](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

аргументом like должен быть шаблон.

Если нужно найти все `pv.name` содержащие символ `S`, тогда нужно так

```
pv.name like '%S%'
```

Если все, которые должны начинаться на `S`, тогда

```
pv.name like 'S%'
```

**upd**

посмотрел структуру. Думаю, что Вам будет достаточно такого

```
pv.name = 'S'
```

Comment: Я так уже пробовал, не помогло.
Товаришь выше уже сказал, чтьо я в Order By всунул свое условие, но оно там бесполезно. Пытаюсь понять, как сделать правильно.

Answer (score 3):

Вот ваш SQL-код, только представленный в читаемом виде:

```
    SELECT p.id, 
           p.url, 
           p.brand_id, 
           p.name, 
           p.annotation, 
           p.body, 
           p.position, 
           p.created as created,
           p.visible, 
           p.featured, 
           p.meta_title, 
           p.meta_keywords, 
           p.meta_description, 
           b.name as brand, 
           b.url as brand_url
      FROM s_products p 
INNER JOIN s_products_categories pc ON pc.product_id = p.id 
       AND pc.category_id IN('10','11','6')
 LEFT JOIN s_brands b ON p.brand_id = b.id 
     WHERE 1 
       AND p.visible=1  
  GROUP BY p.id 
  ORDER BY (SELECT pv.price 
              FROM s_variants pv
             WHERE (pv.stock IS NULL OR pv.stock>0) 
               AND p.id = pv.product_id 
               AND pv.position = (SELECT MIN(position) and pv.name like'S' 
                                    FROM s_variants
                                   WHERE (stock>0 OR stock IS NULL) 
                                     AND product_id = p.id 
                                     LIMIT 1) 
             LIMIT 1)
     LIMIT 0, 4
```

Меня смущает вот этот фрагмент:

```
INNER JOIN s_products_categories pc ON pc.product_id = p.id 
       AND pc.category_id IN('10','11','6')
 LEFT JOIN s_brands b ON p.brand_id = b.id 
     WHERE 1 
       AND p.visible=1
```

и этот:

```
AND pv.position = (SELECT MIN(position) and pv.name like'S'
```

и этот:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT pv.price
```

Собственно, дайте развернутое описание своей БД, уберите лишние поля из примера (наличие/отсутствие которых никак не влияет на понимание сути вопроса, однако отвлекает) и тогда будет понятно, что делать с запросом. Пока это выглядит как выполнение работы за автора.